# Getting this error after running `bin/rake` in my terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the error message below after running `bin/rake` in my terminal.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

My terminal error output is as follows:

`` treehouse:~/projects/odot (master *) $ bin/rake
/home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -I/home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib:/home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-support-3.0.4/lib -S /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/exe/rspec ./spec/controllers/todo_items_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/todo_lists_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_items/complete_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_items/create_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_items/delete_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_items/edit_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_items/index_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_lists/create_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_lists/destroy_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/todo_items_helper_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/todo_lists_helper_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/users_helper_spec.rb ./spec/models/todo_item_spec.rb ./spec/models/todo_list_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_spec.rb ./spec/requests/todo_lists_spec.rb ./spec/routing/todo_lists_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/users_routing_spec.rb ./spec/views/todo_items/index.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/todo_lists/edit.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/todo_lists/index.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/todo_lists/new.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/todo_lists/show.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/users/edit.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/users/new.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/users/show.html.erb_spec.rb
/home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails_helper (LoadError)
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/treehouse/projects/odot/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1058:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1058:in `each'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1058:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
/home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -I/home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib:/home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-support-3.0.4/lib -S /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/exe/rspec ./spec/controllers/todo_items_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/todo_lists_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_items/complete_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_items/create_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_items/delete_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_items/edit_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_items/index_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_lists/create_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_lists/destroy_spec.rb ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/todo_items_helper_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/todo_lists_helper_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/users_helper_spec.rb ./spec/models/todo_item_spec.rb ./spec/models/todo_list_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_spec.rb ./spec/requests/todo_lists_spec.rb ./spec/routing/todo_lists_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/users_routing_spec.rb ./spec/views/todo_items/index.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/todo_lists/edit.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/todo_lists/index.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/todo_lists/new.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/todo_lists/show.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/users/edit.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/users/new.html.erb_spec.rb ./spec/views/users/show.html.erb_spec.rb failed
treehouse:~/projects/odot (master *) $ ``

Answer (score 0):

It says /home/treehouse/projects/odot/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb is failing to load rails_helper.rb.

Comment: How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I don't know why is it failing to load rails_helper.rb.  You can try to just run rspec and see if it gives you a more helpful error.  I think running rspec on /home/treehouse/projects/odot/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb is a good start.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try